# Cannot change attributes of configuration ':app:debugCompile' after it has been resolved

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Cannot change attributes of configuration ':app:debugCompile' after it has been resolved

When I update `AndroidStudio` to `3.3` and use `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'、org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin：1.3.0+`

As I known it works well when I remove

```
{ apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'},
```

But how resolve this problem when my projects have to use kotlin?

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Comment: This may be a bug. Please report this at [kotl.in/issue](https://kotl.in/issue). If your project is an open-source one, please share it as well. If it's not, you can share a minimized sample (with no sources, dependencies, and private identifiers). Also, the log from a build run with a `--stacktrace` command line argument could help, too.

Answer (score 1):

In my project if i add
kotlin after `com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-client` i have the same problem:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-client'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

try to move your `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` 
the most to the top.

Good luck!